# SPFX - Extension - Can't convert library document to pdf

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to convert a word document in a SharePoint Online library to pdf from a custom SPFX extension

I have managed to use the graph api to get a link to the original file using following graph call:
/sites/{site-Id}/drives/{drive-id}/root:/document.docx

This works and returns the expected result. So I now know the document exists and that authentication, etc... is working correctly.

Now I'm asking to convert that document to pdf:

/sites/{site-Id}/drives/{drive-id}/root:/document.docx:/content?format=pdf
This doesn't work, I receive the error:

TypeError: Failed to fetch

Status=-1

PS:I'm using the beta end-point

Can somebody confirm this is an issue with current beta endpoint (doesn't work on SharePoint libraries?) or does anybody see what I'm doing wrong here?

Could this be a setting that must be enabled on our tenant?

Here is the code that I'm using to get graph result:

```
var url:string = "/sites/" +this.context.pageContext.site.id.toString()+ 
"/drives/" + this.driveId +
"/root:/"+ name +":/content?format=pdf"        
this.graphClient.api(url)        
.version("beta")
.get((error, response: any, rawResponse?: any) => {
      console.log(response);
      console.log(rawResponse);
      console.log(error);
});
```

If I want to get the original content instead of pdf, I just remove the "content?format=pdf" from the url and I do get the expected result:

```
var url:string = "/sites/" +this.context.pageContext.site.id.toString()+ 
"/drives/" + this.driveId +
"/root:/"+ name;
this.graphClient.api(url)        
.version("beta")
.get((error, response: any, rawResponse?: any) => {
      console.log(response);
      console.log(rawResponse);
      console.log(error);
});
```

The request for converting to pdf is not malformed because I can execute the request in the Graph Explorer, so this must be a problem with graphClient, but how to resolve it?

Best regards,

Peter

Comment: That doesn't look like a Graph error. Is there any additional error information? There should be a request and a correlation id.

Comment: Unfortunately not Marc. It's the only information returned

Comment: What I see now is that if I use the development console on the Graph Explorer website the request is executed and a location is returned… so can anybody explain why it's failing with the msGraphClientFactory on an SPFX extension?

Comment: seems like i'm not the only one with the issue: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/3077

Comment: On Chrome it does work, with a location header coming back, response type is "cors"... so how to make this also work on Edge?